# Angular2+ apply class to element outside of component

Tags: angular, angular2-components

Long story short I want to display a side-bar beside my router-outlet depending on which component is being rendered, what I have looks something like this:

```html
<div class="content-wrapper clearfix" [class.show-sidebar]='showSidebar'>
    <div class="router-wrapper">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
        <sidebar></sidebar>
    </div> 
</div>
```

So basically certain components need to make the sidebar go away, I'm not sure what the cleanest approach is, my first thought was I could bind the class to a field in a service that could be injected into any components that need to hide/show the sidebar it would work but doesn't seem right to me...

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of the router outlet events

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

And then in the component containing the router-outlet implement the onActivate method:

```
public onActivate(event : any) {
    console.log(event); // here you get hold of all the component and now you can make a variable true false and use ngif or hidden to show or hide the navbar
}
```